# Is this result in general true for lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that if $f,g$ and continuous on $[a,b]$ and if $f=g$ a.e. on $[a,b]$, then in fact $f=g$ on $[a,b]$. Moreover, I found the following:

> > Let $f,g$ be two continuous functions such that $f = g$ a.e. Then $f = g$ everywhere.

I want to know that if we replace $[a,b]$ by a general Lebesgue measurable set $E$, the same results holds.

Comment: I think you'd need to make some restrictions on your measure. What if it is the zero measure or "infinite" measure?

Comment: I fixed, I want to know if the result holds for Lebesgue measurable sets. thanks

Comment: I think you would have a clearer idea if you rephrased the statement to read that "if $f$ and $g$ agree on a dense subset of $[a,b]$ then $f=g$ everywhere."  It's more about the denseness and less about measure theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's false : let's consider $E=F=\{0,1\}$, $f:E\to F$ defined by $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $g:E\to F$ defined by $g(0)=g(1)=1$. See that $E$ and $F$ are measurables and $f$ and $g$ are continuous, but $f=g$ a.e. and $f\neq g$.

Comment: @Ricardo Cervantes : you're welcome !